# Passing a list to a new list with a dynamic name after each step of a loop

Tags: python, loops, rename

I have a data frame with that contains several columns.
I would like to iterate  some columns of the data frame and convert each row to a list based on a function called tokenizer.

```
columns = ['stemmed', 'lemmatized', 'lem_stop','stem_stop', 'lem_stop_nltk', 'stem_stop_nltk']

tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')

sentences = []
for i in columns:
    for tweet in df[i]:
        sentences += tweet_to_sentences(tweet, tokenizer)
```

However, I would like to create 6 different lists rather than one.
How can I change the name of the variable based on variable i in each step of the first loop (i.e. for i in columns:)

I was thinking something like this

```
for i in columns:
    for tweet in df[i]:
        sentences += tweet_to_sentences(tweet, tokenizer)
     i_list = sentences
```

where i_list will translate in `stemmed_list, lemmatized_list, lem_stop_list and so on.`
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Papa,

Perhaps I'm wrong with what you're asking, but what I'm hearing is that each time you iterate 'i' in your for loop you want to dynamically create a list(with a new name)?

If i could suggest a new approach based on this understanding, it'd be to create a list of lists, and each time you go into the for loop you can create a new list and add it as an element to this list of lists. Perhaps a better solution than this would be to create a dictionary, have the list name 'stemmed' be the key and the list you create in the for loop be the value.

Would this work for you?

Comment: @A.Papa if you dont follow my explanation I'm happy to give you pseudocode

Comment: I understand your argument, but I would prefer a new list each time. Is it possible to do so by combining a variable such "New_list" and then adding the "i" variable name such as  New_list_+i.name = sentences and therefore the new list will be New_list_stemmed, New_list_lemmatized etc...

Comment: You get the exact same functionality and end result with the approach of storing a string/list combination in a dictionary. I'm not a seasoned python user, so i'm not sure if what your asking is possible, however i can imagine it's not advised.